# Show popupson hover doesn't work with WMS layer

Tags: wms, layers, web-mapping, qgis2web

I am using qgis2web on QGIS for making a simple webmap. I imported a WMS layer (road) and i exported the webmap with "show popups hover" checked.But popups it doesn't work.

[image]

When i put the layer from my pc (shapefile not WMS) the popups works.

I am something wrong or popups combined with WMS layers It doesn't supported;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, features in WMS layer cannot currently be queried. If the layer is available as a WFS, that can be queried, or, as you have discovered, a shapefile.

There is an open feature request for this, but it has not yet been implemented: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/121